# ¿Cómo convertir esta función de JavaScript a C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

No sé nada de C#, y tengo esta función en código JavaScript que necesito convertir a código C#:

```
convertStringToDate = (fecha) => {
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const añoActual = fechaActual.getFullYear();
    const mesActual = fechaActual.getMonth() + 1;
    const diaActual = fechaActual.getDate();

    var date_str_iso = `${fecha.slice(2, 4)}/${fecha.slice(0, 2)}/${fecha.slice(4, 6)} ${fecha.slice(6, 8)}:${fecha.slice(8, 10)}:${fecha.slice(10, 12)}`
    var date_obj = new Date(Date.parse(date_str_iso));
    date_obj = date_obj.toLocaleString();

    var año = `${20}${fecha.slice(4, 6)}`;
    var mes = fecha.slice(2, 4);
    var dia = fecha.slice(0, 2);

    año = parseInt(año);
    mes = parseInt(mes);
    dia = parseInt(dia);

    if (año <= añoActual) {
        // AÑO ES CORRECTO
        if (mes <= mesActual) {
            // MES ES CORRECTO
            if (dia <= diaActual) {
                // DIA ES CORRECTO
                // TODO ES CORRECTO
            }
        }
    } else { date_obj = "Invalid Date"; };

    return date_obj;
}
```

Donde lo que intento lograr es lo siguiente: La función recibe una cadena que representa una fecha en formato `ddMMyyHHmmss`. Ejemplo: `061023130530`.

Intenté este código:

```
public DateTimeOffset ParseLotDate(string Lot)
{
    var format = "ddMMyyHHmmss";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Lot, format, CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);

    var date = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);

    return date;
}
```

Pero me da error.

Comment: Buenas, en principio m'he copiado tu función y el formato, y por lo que veo funciona, ha de tener presente que DateTimeOffset convierte el Datetime respecto la hora internacional, parece por lo que tienes en javascript solo te interesa la data no la hora ¿me equivoco?

Comment: También recomiendo si usa parseExact que use la CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ya que el formato ya le pasas tú.

Comment: Hola ImSilent, lamentablemente tu pregunta va a ser cerrada, yo te aconsejaría que si no sabes nada de C#, no te embarques, no tiene sentido, aunque alguien te conteste rápido y puedas acceder a la respuesta, después no podrás hacer modificaciones, ni agregados ni nada... en fin, es solo una opinión.

Comment: @MarcePuente yo creo que al menos no hacerle todo, sino intentar arreglar el código de c# que puso, Así como darle las herramientas.

Comment: @rexxarcat, tienes todo mi apoyo!!, no voy a ser yo quien cierre la pregunta

Comment: Yo lo que necesito para ser más exacto es.
¿Cómo se convierte una cadena como 061023130530  en un DateTime?

Comment: ¿Sabes que en Javascript puedes convertir el string a una fecha? Porque puede simplificar el código. En C# también

Answer (score 0):

Buenas la función arreglada que buscas si tienes que devolver un string con el formato que has comentado en los comentarios es el siguiente :

```
 public string ParseLotDate(string Lot)//en caso de consola canviar la cabecera por lo siguiente: public static string ParseLotDate(string Lot)
    {
        string format = "ddMMyyHHmmss";

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Lot, format, CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);

        string date =Lot+" "+ dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");//to string convierte los datetime en string i el formato es lo de dentro
    //+ es para concatenar strings 
        return date;
    }
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te olvidas del DatetimeOffset, ya que convierte fecha en formato internacional, y usa Datetime solo recomiendo declarar las variables por sus tipos y usar CultureInfo.InvariantCulture cuando pasas un formato. Aun así te recomiendo aprender lo básico porque las culturas ya es un poco más avanzado de que sirven los tipos, etc.

Comment: Para cosas de uso básico puedes ir https://www.w3schools.com/cs/index.php para ver las difencias en c# con javascript en caso de consultar cosas con más detalle te tendrás que referir en los documentos de microsoft y si te encallas o tienes errores puedes preguntar aquí

Comment: Me sale este error :
cannot implicity convert type `string `to system.dateTimeOffSet

Comment: Lo he comentado en los comentarios del pero es probable que si lo este probando en consola te este dando error ya que la cabecera tiene que incluir la etiqueta static:
`public static string ParseLotDate(string Lot)`

Comment: la funcion ahora devuelve un string no un datetimeOffset

Comment: El datetimeOffset Convierte en horario internacional un datetime

Comment: Y si yo quiero que me devuelva un dateTimeOffSet ?

Comment: Si querias que devuelva un datetimeOffset lo que tenias originalmente ya era completamente valido

Comment: Y que se supone que me devuelve la función que tenía originalmente ?

Comment: Un datetimeOffset te lo indica en la cabecera

Comment: Pero se puede crear una funcion que inicie asi ?
        public DateTimeOffset ParseLotDate(string Lot)
        {
}

Comment: Si asi, es un ejemplo correcto de declarar una funcion. Esto indica de izquierda a derecha que la funcion es publica, que devuelve un DateTimeOffset, su Nombre es "ParseLotDate" y requiere un parametro de tipo string lote

Comment: Pero a veces si usas la consola u otros es necesario declararlo como statico eso se hace como: public static DateTimeOffset ParseLotDate(string Lot){}